# rsync and crontab

Tags: ssh, backup, cron, rsync

Hi I am trying to backup an ubuntu 16.04 server to a freeNAS backup server using rsync and crontab.

The command I am using for rsync is

```
sudo rsync --delete --delete-excluded -az /home/backups/ root@192.168.1.6:/mnt/backupvol/production_nfs/db-server-master/
```

When I run this command from command line first it asks for sudo password then root password for `192.168.1.6`. Then command is executed as expected.

when I try to `sudo ssh root@192.168.1.6` then also it asked for both passwords. I have tried to use `sudo ssh-copy-id root@192.168.1.6` and have copied the keys successfully.

My question is

1. How do I bypass password entry
2. when I run rsync command with crontab I am getting wrong password errors

How do I correct these?

Answer (score 1):

First, do Not try to use `sudo` in a `cron` job. `sudo` has nowhere to prompt for the password.

Run your command in `root`'s `crontab` - the `/etc/crontab` file. Edit this file directly, Not with `sudo crontab -e`. The `/etc/crontab` file has a non-standard format, so read the comments at the front of the file carefully.

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo crontab -e`? That actually edits `root`'s crontab whereas `/etc/crontab` is the system-wide crontab.